# How to display a text with dots when resizing the browser window?

Tags: javascript, css

How can I display my text with dots when I resize the browser window using CSS ?

Eg:

My text

'Hello world! Welcome to Coding'

After resizing

Hello world! Welcome to Co...

Hello world! Welcome t...
(Would display dots according to resizing of window)

Comment: Using [`text-overflow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow) might help you

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS.

```
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can archive this using **text-overflow: ellipsis;overflow: hidden;white-space: nowrap;**

For more information go to: [text-overflow](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-overflow.asp)

Let me know if you have a any question about this.

Hope this help you

```css
    .app a {
  width: 140px;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 5px 0 5px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="app">
  <a href="">Hello world! Welcome to Coding</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is a basic example of how to use `text-overflow: ellipsis;`. You need the `overflow: hidden;` property to be present as well as `white-space: nowrap;`

HTML: `<p class="overflow"> this text will not wrap and will show the ellipsis when it is wider than the screen width</p>`

CSS:

```
.overflow {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```